# For loop for small arrays?

Tags: c++, performance

In my code, I have to manage small groups of data. For example, some of my code could look like this:

> ```
> bool flag0, flag1, flag2, flag3;
> int val0, val1, val2, val3;
>
> flag0 = GetFlag(0);
> flag1 = GetFlag(1);
> ```
>
> // Do similar stuff from here.

Most of the time, I could easily switch to small array implementation and process them using for loops like this:

> ```
> bool flag[4];
> int val[4];
>
> for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
>      flag[i] = GetFlag(i);
> ```
>
> ...

I know the 2nd approach produces more readable code than the 1st, but for the sake of inquiry..

Would the 1st approach generally perform better? Does it use less memory or run faster thanks to not having for loop overheads or array overheads?

Let's assume the code doesn't utilize multi-threading for simplicity's sake, and also because I don't think my program uses it.

Any overall assessment of the two? What do you think?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Stop doing micro optimisation. You end up wasting lots of time without any significant performance improvements. Remember the 80-20 rule.

Comment: This is small stuff. Don't sweat it. Use the more readable and maintainable version using arrays and loops.

Comment: Your compiler can optimize that far better than you will be able to.

Comment: basic idea why do we use loop, to avoid repetition of codes

Comment: When I see `int val0, val1, val2, val3;`, I start looking for where these get initialized... and start beating heads if it is halfway down the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all [micro-optimzation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding) such this one are irrelevant until you prove they're relevant.

Regarding your specific question at least two possible compiler optimization comes into my mind:

- [Loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling), which basically translates your loop into a version without the loop at all, and it could possibly easily be applied to your case
- [Automatic parallelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_parallelization), which could be able to parallelize the loop over multiple processor, but things here get more complicated since the compiler must be able to produce multiple assumptions

So in conclusion, don't avoid using loops when you can have more readable and maintainable code.

Comment: Yet again I underestimate the power of compilers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called 'loop unrolling'.  Compilers will do it for you automatically as a part of the code optimization step there is no need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

for C code such as that, I don't think it will matter how you write it.
The GCC compiler, when using the -O2 or -O3 flag for optimization, will do it's thing.  Using the -O3 flag gives you the fastest running code.  So i would write it with human readability in mind.
One other thing that can help is not using one variable to do everything; it can be sometimes be faster if you declare more variables each having a specific use in a section or function of the program.  But again i believe what has the most influence is the compiler and the optimization flag chosen.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options